# Using spawn_posix to launch pkg (Writing Autoupdater for audio plugin)

Tags: c++, macos, package

I'm writing an auto-updater for my audio plugin which is working fine on Windows, and I feel I'm close on MAC but need some help understanding how to programmatically launch the installer on mac. The algorithm is pretty simple:

1. Plugin checks in S3 to see if there's a newer version
2. If YES then plugin downloads the installer for the new version
3. Once downloaded the plugin should launch the installer and prompt the user to close the DAW (audio workstation)

This is working fine, I can download the installer on both platforms, and on windows launch it by using CreateProcess, but I can't find the right way to do it on mac. The closest equivalent I can find is "posix_spawn" in order to launch a process and then run "/user/sbin/installer -pkg /path/to/pkg /target", and although this is returning 0 indicating success I don't see any installer popping up on the screen. Ideally the user would see the UI of the installer as there are some options included.

How can I accomplish the goal of opening a PKG file visually for the user on mac using C++? OR, is there an alternative solution to accomplish the algorithm described above? Many thanks!

Comment: Check the [Sparkle](https://sparkle-project.org) project. You can either use it or [learn how it works](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle).

Comment: `system("/path/to/your/pkg.pkg")`

Comment: Thank you! system("open /path/to/pkg.pkg") worked perfectly :)